# How contact directly people on ROS?

Tags: ros, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

you may be able to contact a person registered on this portal ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165236/how-contact-directly-people-on-ros-?/) by [mrshifo](https://answers.ros.org/users/14531/mrshifo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe there´s no way to do that, but for many users you´ll be able to search for their name on the internet and find out contact data this way. If a person doesn´t have enough info in their profile for this to work, they probably do not want this to be possible :)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0